# How to get stock status from product collection in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

here is my product collection can anyone help to get me stock status from product collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($categoryId)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG));
return $collection;
```

Answer (score 6):

Stock status (`is_in_stock`) is part of every product collection.

```
foreach ($collections as $product) {
    echo $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock();
}
```

Returns `1` if in stock, else `null`.

If you need other stock information like `min_qty` or `backorders` you can add this to your collection:

```
$collection->setFlag('require_stock_items', true);
```

---

<sup>More details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106455/get-product-stock-quantity-in-magento/209510#209510</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($categoryId)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')        
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG));
    return $collection;
```

Here you can do it like this

You have to add join Field for stock items `->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.is_in_stock=1','left')`

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: ok thank you so much sir for the help. it is working fine. :)